# I got error : "missing) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Got error:

> missing ) after the argument list

```
$('.next-btn').append("<a class="actionsubmit" ng-click="onSubmit('hello.html')">Check</a>");
```

Comment: oh - well, now it's obvious - because of your assumption that javascript knows when a `"` marks the beginning and end of a string

Comment: $('.next-btn').append("<a class="actionsubmit" ng-click="onSubmit('hello.html')">Check</a>");             This is the code i got error

Comment: `"<a class="` is a string ... followed immediately by `actionsubmit` is invalid - you need to escape your inner `"` ... like `$('.next-btn').append("<a class=\"actionsubmit\" ng-click=\"onSubmit('hello.html')\">Check</a>");`

Comment: Give some more details.

Comment: would you kindly edit my code ?

Comment: Kindly edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is simply a Syntax issue. If you use `"` to wrap your String data, it will be ended with `"` as well. You can use `'` inside if you need.

Comment: $('.next-div').append("<a class=\"actionsubmit\" ng-click=\"onSubmit('hello.html')\">Check </a>");        hello guys, Sorry, But this LINE OF CODE doesn't add anchor to ".next-div" class

Comment: @sakthikumaran what element is `$('.next-btn')`?

Comment: @sakthikumaran it would be best to provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: its a div class

Comment: @sakthikumaran what event is this code executed under? Please see previous comment ^^^

Comment: Also you can use template string supported in ES6.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to escape special characters inside your append string,

```
$('.next-btn').append("<a class=\"actionsubmit\" ng-click=\"onSubmit('hello.html')\">Check</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is generated by syntax issues.

Your Code:

```
$('.next-btn').append("<a class="actionsubmit" ng-click="onSubmit('hello.html')">Check</a>");
```

You cannot use `"` inside this string without escaping it. For example:

```
$('.next-btn').append("<a class=\"actionsubmit\" ng-click=\"onSubmit('hello.html')\">Check</a>");
```

Please read: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

> Because strings must be written within quotes, JavaScript will misunderstand this string:
>
> `var x = "We are the so-called "Vikings" from the north.";`
>
> The string will be chopped to "We are the so-called ". The solution to avoid this problem, is to use the backslash escape character. The backslash (`\`) escape character turns special characters into string characters.

Now you can also create the element in jQuery. Advised code:

```
var newA = $("<a>", {
  class: "actionsubmit",
  "ng-click": "onSubmit('hello.html')"
}).html("Check");
$('.next-btn').append(newA);
```

Hope that helps.